# Dataproperty and ObjectProperty with equal names

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

Consider code below:

```
OWLClass clsA = factory.getOWLClass("cls_A", pm);
OWLAxiom axiom = factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(clsA);
manager.addAxiom(ontology, axiom);

OWLClass clsB = factory.getOWLClass("cls_B", pm);
axiom = factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(clsB);
manager.addAxiom(ontology, axiom);

OWLObjectProperty propA = factory.getOWLObjectProperty("prop", pm);
axiom = factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(propA);
manager.addAxiom(ontology, axiom);

OWLDataProperty propB = factory.getOWLDataProperty("prop", pm);
axiom = factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(propB);
manager.addAxiom(ontology, axiom);

axiom = factory.getOWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom(propA, clsA);
manager.addAxiom(ontology, axiom);

axiom = factory.getOWLDataPropertyDomainAxiom(propB, clsB);
manager.addAxiom(ontology, axiom);
```

this code creates OP with 2 domain classes and DP with no domain class. How to create domain property for data property if there is object property with same name ? Is it bug ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's allowed to create an object property and a data property that have the same IRI...

Comment: Not, that's definitely not allowed in OWL 2 DL: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning   "...OWL 2 DL still imposes certain restrictions: it requires that a name cannot be used for both a class and a datatype and that **a name can only be used for one kind of property**."

Comment: Rewrite it as a answer so I can close this. Thanks